# How to use javascript origin addEventListener in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write some origin javascript before load angularjs like this:

```
<ng-app>
  <ng-controller>
    <element />
  </ng-controller>
  <script>
    element.addEventListener('click', some_function);
  </script>
  <script src='angularjs.js'></script>
</ng-app>
```

This code for add some feature before angularjs init when mobile network like 2G/3G. I hope `element.click` event can run whatever angularjs init.

I found angularjs replace element event for `html.ng-scope` after loaded.

[image: dont-use-angular]
[image]

How to use javascript origin addEventListener in angularjs or disable this strange behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: $apply also included angularjs. 
I want to run origin javascript event before angularjs init and I hope angularjs dont touch my event.

Answer (score 0):

use element.on('click', some_function); instead..
cause element is in JQuery (Console it if you want) and .on is jquery method as well to listen events.

And addEventListener is a JS method. SO if you still wanna use it then convert element to
html first
Thanks,
Vaibhav